# Why doesn't jquery fadeIn() work with .html()?

Tags: jquery, fadein

When you click you a checkbox I want the message to fade in slowly.

**Why doesn't .fadeIn() work in this example?**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Text XHTML Page</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>       
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="checkboxList">
        <div class="title">Languages:</div>
        <div class="row"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/><span class="label">Ruby</span></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="checkbox"/><span class="label">PHP</span></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="checkbox"/><span class="label">C#</span></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="checkbox"/><span class="label">Python</span></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="checkbox"/><span class="label">JavaScript</span></div>
    </div>
    <p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript:**

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

//run when page is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

    $('.checkboxList .row').css('color','red');
    $('.checkboxList input').attr('checked', true);
    $('.checkboxList input').bind('click', function() {
        $('#message').html("You clicked on a checkbox.").fadeIn('slow');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

No fadeIn is done because the #message element is visible, hide it, add the content and fade it in:

```
$('#message').hide().html("You clicked on a checkbox.").fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: A Content Management System in the form of a human being - awesome!

Comment: What if I add several `li` elements after 1sec one by one and want to show with your solution? How to just fadein the li I added not all li's? Like `$("#oFnav").append("<li class='hideOFl'>Business Process Study</li>").hide().fadeIn(fadeIndur);`. It hides and fadein all lis not just addeed.

Comment: Modified: `$('#message').fadeOut('slow').html("You clicked on a checkbox.").fadeIn('slow');` will let the faded in html blink 2 times... funny bug :P

Answer (score 11):

after analize this problem, that I have to solve, this is my code, that works to use fadeout, change html and fadein

```
$("#div_big_picture").fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $(this).html("<img src='" + str_to_load + "' height='800px' />")
}).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea why but I've had trouble chaining this before.  You can get the effect you want by using this less elegant code:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

//run when page is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

    $('.checkboxList .row').css('color','red');
    $('.checkboxList input').attr('checked', true);
    $('.checkboxList input').bind('click', function() {
        $('#message').hide(); //just in case
        $('#message').html("You clicked on a checkbox.");
        $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
    });

});
```

Comment: this feels like voodoo code, you know? Like, the chaining works, but there was probably something that you missed when you tried it, so you've reverted to the dodgier method because it works. It's a dangerous habit to get into...

Comment: Agree... never took the time to figure out why it did not work... but I see CMS' answer explains it.  Good to know.