# how to fadeIn .html()

Tags: jquery, html, animation, dom-manipulation

```
$('.overview li a').click(function(){
        $('#large-img').html("<img src=" + $(this)
                           .attr('href') + "/>" + "<br /><div>" + $(">.desc",this)
                           .html()); //HOW TO FADEIN this
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't jquery fadeIn() work with .html()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490563/why-doesnt-jquery-fadein-work-with-html)

Answer (score 4):

`.fadeIn()` can only be called on jQuery collections. `html()` returns a string, so it cannot be used on that. One possible route is to create a jQuery collection out of your HTML (that you want to insert), hide it, then append it to its place and fade it in.

This code does this:

```
$('.overview li a').click(function(){
    var $newstuff=
        $("<img src=" 
        + $(this).attr('href') 
        + ">"
        + "<br><div>" 
        + $(">.desc", this).html()
        + '</div>').hide();

    $('#large-img').append($newstuff.fadeIn('slow'));
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4M3DJ/)

And the same code in a bit more jQuery-ish way:

```
$('.overview li a').click(function(){  
    $('<img>').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
        .add('<br>')
        .add($('<div>').html($(">.desc", this).html()))
        .hide()
        .appendTo($('#large-img'))
        .fadeIn('slow'); 
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4M3DJ/2/)

Comment: hi i have a problem with the image path it adds a slash at the end "img.jpg/" the server cant read it when i upload

Comment: @user555600 I would gladly help, but as a developer yourself, you understand that it would quite hard without knowing your HTML, your exact URL you have problem with and possibly your browser. Best way would be to create a test case or jsFiddle and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$('.overview li a').click(function(){
    var a = this;
    var img = $("<img src='" + $(this).attr('href') + "'/>" +  "<br /><div>");
    $('#large-img').hide('fast', function(){ 
        $(this).html(img + $(">.desc", a)).show('fast'); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: hi i have a problem with the image path it adds a slash at the end "img.jpg/" the server cant read it when i upload