# jQuery JSON fadein - not working?

Tags: jquery, json, fadein, setinterval

Something is going awry with this code but it's late and I just can't figure it out:

```
var json_object = '.$json_twitter_array.';

function displayTweets(obj){
    $("#tweetblock").html(obj[0].description).fadeIn("slow");
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $("#tweetblock").html(obj[i].description).fadeIn("slow");
            i++;
            if(i >= obj.length) i = 0;
        },6000);
}
displayTweets(json_object);
```

it's looping through the json object just fine, the problem is the fadeIn is not working, the text is just displayed.  Can someone point out where I'm going wrong/missing the obvious?

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1490563/1026459 , also probable lack of any troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are fading the object after the content is actual placed.  A quick way to get around this is to add a `hide()` to each element before the `html()` happens, then the content is added to the hidden area, and then after that `fadeIn()` kicks in.

So each:

```
$("#tweetblock").html
```

Becomes:

```
$("#tweetblock").hide().html
```

And the final code should look like:

```
var json_object = '.$json_twitter_array.';

function displayTweets(obj){
    $("#tweetblock").hide().html(obj[0].description).fadeIn("slow");
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $("#tweetblock").hide().html(obj[i].description).fadeIn("slow");
            i++;
            if(i >= obj.length) i = 0;
        },6000);
}
displayTweets(json_object);
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, it looks so simple with your explanation but I just couldn't work it out on Friday night.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to fade it out before you can fade it back in again!

`fadeIn` and `fadeOut` only change the visibility of an element. They don't do anything when the content changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just do one thing in css:

```
#tweetblock{
   display:none;
}
```

Then `fadeIn()` will occur.