# .hover() functionality working but elements that should be hidden are still visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, hoverintent

I'm pretty new to jquery / javascript but I've created a main navigation element. The idea is that a user hovers over a specific `<li>` (that is split into 2 `divs`). Only div1 is visible to start. When hover occurs the height on div1 is animated to 0 to reveal div2.

However, when the height animates to 0 the content of div1 (specifically look for the white h2 and h3 type) is still visible behind type of div2 (intermittently). If you mess with the `<li>`'s you can get this to stop happening but I can't log an error or figure out why it disappears at some points.

[see http://jsfiddle.net/pappley/BGy6R/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/pappley/BGy6R/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `overflow` to `hidden`:

```
.main-link-title {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BGy6R/4/

Comment: This works– before when I set the height to 0 was I still allowing the contents to be visible? Just want to make sure I understand why this fixes.

Comment: @pappley - Yes. The fact the the container's height is set to 0 is not enough to hide the children; you have to set the overflow to hidden, like I showed you.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653809/jquery-json-fadein-not-working/14653849#14653849) and you should use `hide()` to hide the `<div>` when it is offstage.

Looking at your code, it seems you could do this:

```
$('li').hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).children(':first').stop(true, false).animate({height: '0'}, 1000, 'easeOutQuad').hide();
}, function() {
    $(this).children(':first').stop(true, false).show().animate({height: '200px'}, 1000, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

I just added a `.hide()` at the end of the first call which appears to set the height of the `<div>` to `0`? And then added a `show()` prior to the `animate()` in the second one?

Basically, test that out.  The basic concept is to either `hide` or `show` the `<div>` based on the actions & behavior intended.