# fade in after ajax call

Tags: jquery, fadein, effects

I have the following code and try to make the result of the ajax fade in

```
$.post('e.php', {term: $(this).text()} , function(data) {
                $('#dictionary').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
})
```

This is not working. How I must edit it, to make the results fade in the `div`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Everything works fine, except the effect, it doesnt take place. I see the results appear in the `div`, not fade in it.

Comment: Define "not working."  What *is* it doing?  Is the AJAX request made at all?  Does the response have what you expect?  Is the target element (`#dictionary`) found?  Is its HTML set?  Does any fade effect take place?  Where *specifically* does it fail?

Comment: What is the state of the styling for the `#dictionary` element before this code executes?  Is it visible?  (Even if it's empty?)

Comment: @David yes it is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have to do with the fact that `#dictionary` might be visible before the `fadeIn()` call. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490563/why-doesnt-jquery-fadein-work-with-html#1490582).

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> @David yes it is visible

What do you expect `.fadeIn()` to do on an element that's *already visible*?  There's nothing to "fade in."  The element needs to be hidden first.  Either style it to be hidden by default via CSS:

```
#dictionary {
    display: none;
}
```

Or hide it inline with the JavaScript code:

```
$('#dictionary').hide().html(data).fadeIn("slow");
```