# Switch HTML content of div with another piece of HTML without fading out to white first using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to fade from one piece of HTML in a div to another piece of HTML without fading out to white (to the background color of the div) first like i'm doing in this example:

The positionNumber variable is just an int with the number (e.g. 3).

```
function changeContent(positionNumber) {
    $('.banner-content-wrapper').fadeOut('fast', function() {

        var contentHtml = $('.slidercontent#' + positionNumber).html();

        $('.banner-content-wrapper').hide().fadeIn(1000).html(contentHtml);
    });
}
```

This example does the exact same by fading to white first but this is not what I'm lookig for:
[Why doesn't jquery fadeIn() work with .html()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490563/why-doesnt-jquery-fadein-work-with-html)

I want to fade directly from one piece of HTML to another. I haven't been able to find any example on Stack Overflow that shows how to do exact that. I know this is not valid code but it's something like this I'm looking for:
$('.banner-content-wrapper').fadeToHtml(contentHtml);

How can I fade directly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuuu405c/

Answer (score 1):

why use fadeOut/fadeIn - why not hide/show

```
function changeContent(positionNumber) {
    $('.banner-content-wrapper').hide('fast', function() {

        var contentHtml = $('.slidercontent#' + positionNumber).html();

        $('.banner-content-wrapper').hide().html(contentHtml).show();
    });
}
```

I have not tested this - just a suggestion based on the example you referenced

Comment: actually, I think mastahb's answer is the one you should use

Comment: Hi phpmydev. Thank you for your answer. Because hide and show doesn't fade. I want to fade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use fade. Try to use Replace.

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: Thank you for the example mastahb.

It works but it doesn't fade unfortunately. I need it to fade.
I'm doing it like this:
`$(".banner-image-wrapper").replaceWith('<div class="banner-image-wrapper">' + contentHtml + '</div>');`

Comment: And another example that doeesn't fade directly:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Dubr/1/

Please help me figure out how to fade directly without fading to white (transparent) first